# Issue using form in Google app in mobile

Tags: plugins, custom-field, forms, contact

I have a contact form on my website, and I'm utilizing Contact Form 7 (CF7) plugin for it. However, when I fill out the form using the Google app on my mobile device, the page seems to reload somehow.

I haven't encountered this issue when filling out forms using Chrome or any other browser on my mobile. Is there a solution for this, or could it be an inherent issue with the Google app itself?

for better explanation here demonstration [video](https://warehouse.activecollab.com/api/v1/files/2024-03%2F7e7e40130d31eb370b364cdbb3d664f1f72b54b05028c7cc526d193f33503aae5abb28f35dc328f264ee29fa529e94855230c114b8f65dfb6153a0a429871348.mp4/bef14bdbefa3120aaa5b3ff223788502/preview?intent=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwczpcL1wvYXBwLmFjdGl2ZWNvbGxhYi5jb21cLzE0OTE3MSIsImlhdCI6MTcxMDk5ODIyNCwiZXhwIjoxNzExMDg0NjI0LCJhdWQiOiJodHRwczpcL1wvd2guYWN0aXZlY29sbGFiLmNvbSIsImVtYWlsIjoiYmFpbUB3aGVsbG8uaWQiLCJpbnRlbnQiOiJwcmV2aWV3IiwiYWNjb3VudF9pZCI6MTQ5MTcxfQ.TwEMqaENJQ5r8lcL73lOcUZ_S_9ecbAnvOT2vyIFHYc)

Comment: What Google App are you using?  This seems like an app issue, not a WordPress issue.